# selenium chrome и headless chrome разный результат при заходе на mail.ru

Tags: python, selenium, mail.ru

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://mail.ru/')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

username = driver.find_element_by_id("login")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")

driver.find_element_by_id("mailbox__auth__button").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

driver.get_screenshot_as_file('mail.png')
```

Если такой код, то в результате получается скриншот внутри ящика, но если добавляю

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
```

то получается ошибка

> "Access to Resource at 'https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/21753/1?cnt-class=1&page-ref=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.ru%2F&...Mail.Ru' from origin ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ... is therefore not allowed access.", source: ... (0)

Почему и что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка указывает, что браузер в целях безопасности блокировал междоменный запрос. Трудно сказать, почему это работает в первом случаи корректно. 
Однако, вы можете полностью отключить проверки безопасности 
`options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')`, в том числе CORS.